# PHP composer autoloader does'nt work on production server

Tags: composer-php, autoload

I implemented an autoloader. Locally, everything works fine, but once i upload it to the production server, all classes are not found.

```
{
    "require": {
        "facebook/php-sdk": "@stable",
        "everyman/neo4jphp": "dev-master",
        "predis/predis": "1.0.1",
        "aws/aws-sdk-php": "2.*"
    },

    "autoload": {
        "psr-0": {
            "PicoCore\\": "",
            "PicoCore\\Authentication\\" : "PicoCore/authentication",
            "PicoCore\\Aws\\" : "PicoCore/aws",
            "PicoCore\\Cache\\" : "PicoCore/cache",
            "PicoCore\\Database\\" : "PicoCore/database",
            "PicoCore\\Database\\Managers\\" : "PicoCore/database/managers",
            "PicoCore\\Facebook\\" : "PicoCore/facebook",
            "PicoCore\\Objects\\" : "PicoCore/objects",
            "PicoCore\\Rest\\" : "PicoCore/rest",
        "PicoCore\\Configuration\\" : "PicoCore/configuration",
            "PicoCore\\Configuration\\Api\\" : "PicoCore/configuration/api",
            "PicoCore\\Configuration\\PictureReceiver\\" : "PicoCore/configurat$
            "PicoCore\\Configuration\\PictureUploader\\" : "PicoCore/configurat$
            "PicoCore\\Scripts\\" : "PicoCore/scripts",
            "PicoCore\\Times" : "PicoCore/times"
        }
    }
}
```

I read here [composer autoload not working on production server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15014561/composer-autoload-not-working-on-production-server) that maybe it because of the \. Is it correct ? And if so, where do i put this funciton?

Comment: What is the classname and path/filename of a class in (for example) the namespace `PicoCore\Authentication`. Your autoload setup is a bit suboptimal because of the first entry and/or the amount of useless directory levels. PSR-0 or even PSR-4 (recommended for namespace classes) would be able to work with only one line of autoload declaration if the directory structure would be changed a bit.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?  I'm having the same problem on a LAMP server.