# PHP Autoloader doesn't work on Ubuntu production server

Tags: php, ubuntu, composer-php

I have to environments i'm working developing my API (PHP based):

1. **Local development:** Mac OS Yosemite - running PHP 5.5.20
2. **Production server:** Ubuntu server - running PHP 5.5.9

My code uses composer for auto loading as followed:

```
{
    "require": {
        "facebook/php-sdk": "@stable",
        "everyman/neo4jphp": "dev-master",
        "predis/predis": "1.0.1",
        "aws/aws-sdk-php": "2.*"
    },

    "autoload": {
        "psr-0": {
            "PicoCore\\": "",
            "PicoCore\\Authentication\\" : "PicoCore/authentication",
            "PicoCore\\Aws\\" : "PicoCore/aws",
            "PicoCore\\Cache\\" : "PicoCore/cache",
            "PicoCore\\Database\\" : "PicoCore/database",
            "PicoCore\\Database\\Managers\\" : "PicoCore/database/managers",
            "PicoCore\\Facebook\\" : "PicoCore/facebook",
            "PicoCore\\Objects\\" : "PicoCore/objects",
            "PicoCore\\Rest\\" : "PicoCore/rest",
            "PicoCore\\Configuration\\" : "PicoCore/configuration",
            "PicoCore\\Configuration\\Api\\" : "PicoCore/configuration/api",
            "PicoCore\\Configuration\\PictureReceiver\\" : "PicoCore/configuration/pictureReceiver",
            "PicoCore\\Configuration\\PictureUploader\\" : "PicoCore/configuration/pictureUploader",
            "PicoCore\\Scripts\\" : "PicoCore/scripts",
            "PicoCore\\Times" : "PicoCore/times"
        }
    }
}
```

This is my loading function:

```
// autoload_namespaces.php @generated by Composer

$vendorDir = dirname(dirname(__FILE__));
$baseDir = dirname($vendorDir);

return array(
    'PicoCore\\Times' => array($baseDir . '/PicoCore/times'),
    'PicoCore\\Scripts\\' => array($baseDir . '/PicoCore/scripts'),
    'PicoCore\\Rest\\' => array($baseDir . '/PicoCore/rest'),
    'PicoCore\\Objects\\' => array($baseDir . '/PicoCore/objects'),
    'PicoCore\\Facebook\\' => array($baseDir . '/PicoCore/facebook'),
    'PicoCore\\Database\\Managers\\' => array($baseDir . '/PicoCore/database/managers'),
    'PicoCore\\Database\\' => array($baseDir . '/PicoCore/database'),
    'PicoCore\\Configuration\\PictureUploader\\' => array($baseDir . '/PicoCore/configuration/pictureUploader'),
    'PicoCore\\Configuration\\PictureReceiver\\' => array($baseDir . '/PicoCore/configuration/pictureReceiver'),
    'PicoCore\\Configuration\\Api\\' => array($baseDir . '/PicoCore/configuration/api'),
    'PicoCore\\Configuration\\' => array($baseDir . '/PicoCore/configuration'),
    'PicoCore\\Cache\\' => array($baseDir . '/PicoCore/cache'),
    'PicoCore\\Aws\\' => array($baseDir . '/PicoCore/aws'),
    'PicoCore\\Authentication\\' => array($baseDir . '/PicoCore/authentication'),
    'PicoCore\\' => array($baseDir . '/'),
    'Guzzle\\Tests' => array($vendorDir . '/guzzle/guzzle/tests'),
    'Guzzle' => array($vendorDir . '/guzzle/guzzle/src'),
    'Everyman\\Neo4j' => array($vendorDir . '/everyman/neo4jphp/lib'),
    'Aws' => array($vendorDir . '/aws/aws-sdk-php/src'),
);
```

When i'm running my code on my local development - it works perfectly, so I pushed it to my remote repository and pull it from the production server.

When i'm trying to run my code in my Production server I receive a `Class not found` error indicating that my autoloading didn't run properly.

Any ideas what could be the reason ?

**UPDATE:**
When i'm trying to load the external libs (like AWS) it does work, so the problem is defiantly something with how my folders are being loaded.

**UPDATE:**
This is the class i'm trying to load from index.php:

```
<?php
//require Pico Core autoload
require 'core/vendor/autoload.php';

//require Pico Api autoload
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

use PicoCore\Rest\ApiInitializer;
use PicoCore\Configuration\Error;
use PicoApi\Managers\ApiManager;

try {
    //initialize the API
    ApiInitializer::initialize();
    //initialize a new Api with the request
    $api = new ApiManager($_REQUEST['request']);
    echo utf8_encode($api->processApi());

} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo json_encode(Array(Error::jsonErrorField() => $e->getMessage()));
}
```

This is the error I receive  `Class 'PicoCore\Rest\ApiInitializer' not found`

The structure is:

```
api
 |
 core
   |
   PicoCore
      |
     folders..
     rest
      |
      ApiInitializer.php
     folders...
    vender
 PicoApi (folder)
 vendor (foldeR)
 index.php
```

Comment: 99% sure it has something to do with directory separators or a hard coded base path. I don't use composer, but are those `/ ` directory separators? Could you post your autoloader function as well?

Comment: @redelschaap I added it. I hope that what you mean :)

Comment: I think the problem is in that last part. Could you change all the `/` to `DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR`? So `$vendorDir . '/aws/aws-sdk-php/src'` becomes `$vendorDir . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'aws' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'aws-sdk-php' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'src'`. And can you verify that `$vendorDir` has the right base path on the production server?

Comment: The $vendorDir and $baseDir are correct. The vendors are not my problem. It doesn't find my own files, no the other libs. I tried to do what you suggested in:     'PicoCore\\Rest\\' => array($baseDir . '/PicoCore/rest'),
since this is the namespace he's looking for but it didn't work

Comment: @redelschaap the external libs works.. its defiantly something with my classes definitions

Comment: You can try to `strace` the process and see what files it really tries to open.

Comment: @redelschaap I think it is useless to try to "fix" autogenerated code of Composer that is running fine on hundred thousand installations with "DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR". PHP does abstract away this from the programmer when using PHP filesystem functions, i.e. the slash "/" is working fine even on Windows where it should in theory be the backslash "\". DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR is meant to be used for system calls like `exec()` that do not have that abstraction layer.

Comment: I am pretty sure @AsafNevo you asked this before, and my comment was to ask you to show the complete name of one such class you are trying to load (namespace and class), together with the full path and filename. My guess is that there is some mismatch in the character case.

Comment: This was the question I'm referring to. It came from a different account. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30889845/php-composer-autoloader-doesnt-work-on-production-server#comment49824186_30889845

Comment: Which class is not found? | The namespace declaration for "PicoCore\\Times" should end with "\\"

Comment: @Sven funny - that's my CTO. I didn't know he posted a question regarding. I'm adding an update to my question

Comment: @Sven I updated my question, but I think its not a matter of character case. It works perfectly on my Mac OS. Wouldn't it break if it was the case ?

Comment: The real question is - why do you even have the whole `vendor` under version control? If you develop your app by splitting it into packages that `composer` is able to load, all you have to deploy is a `composer.json` + a file with specific config options. Then the pulling party just needs to run `composer install` and you're done. This doesn't answer your question, but if you're doing things - do them properly. Doing it properly means less hassle, quicker deployment and no stupid bugs like one you have right now.

Comment: @N.B. word. :) Can you please direct me to resources about the config options and how to do it ?

Comment: There are many, you can even come up with your own stuff, like including a `config.php`. [Lumen](http://lumen.laravel.com) framework uses [dotenv](https://github.com/vlucas/phpdotenv) style configuration, check it out.

Comment: @N.B - a weird thing, i tried to remove vender and composer.lock and reinstalled the composer on the server, and yet it didnt work. Wasnt it supposed to work with composer install?

Comment: It works perfectly on your mac because its case insensitive for filenames.

Comment: Seems like case insensitive is the general case for MacOS even though it's basically a unix. https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/71357/how-to-check-if-my-hd-is-case-sensitive-or-not

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's your wrong autoloading definition.

You want to use the class

```
PicoCore\Rest\ApiInitializer
```

And you have these files:

```
api/index.php
api/vendor/...    (with your required external dependencies)
api/composer.json (with the autoloading mentioned in your question)
api/core/PicoCore/rest/ApiInitializer.php
```

And you have this autoloading configured:

"autoload": {
       "psr-0": {
           "PicoCore\Rest\" : "PicoCore/rest"
       }
    }

This is a mismatch. When you use the class `PicoCore\Rest\ApiInitializer`, composer will try to locate an entry with a prefix of that class. It will sucessfully detect that classes with prefix `PicoCode\Rest` can be found via PSR-0 rules in the directory (relative to the position of `composer.json`) `PicoCore/rest`.

First strange thing: There is an additional directory named "core" here, and you seem to include TWO autoloaders. Don't do that, Composer works best with only one autoloader.

Second thing: If I ignore that "core" directory for a bit, the PSR-0 rules state that the classname will be converted to a path - and then be searched in the path given for the prefix.

`PicoCore\Rest\ApiInitializer` as a path is `PicoCore/Rest/ApiInitializer.php` (note the uppercase "R" in "Rest"), and the path this is to be found is `PicoCore/rest/PicoCore/Rest/ApiInitializer.php`.

You don't have this file. And thats why Composer cannot find and load it. And this is even without counting this "core" directory level, it will also not be found if you used two `composer.json` files, one in `api` and one in `api/core`, and the one in `api/core` was used to find the class.

Suggestions:

1. Use PSR-4 for every class that is inside a namespace.
2. Don't lowercase namespace or classname parts for the filesystem.
3. Shorten your autoloading definition. If you'd rename all those lowercase directories below `PicoCore` into the proper uppercase variants that are being used in your namespace, you will only need one line of autoloading definition, defining the `PicoCore` prefix. The rest is done by PSR-4 (or PSR-0).

MacOS is using a case insensitive file system by default, and it is considered a bad thing to switch it to case sensitive: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/71357/how-to-check-if-my-hd-is-case-sensitive-or-not That's why it is working on Mac, but not Linux.

Comment: thank you for this detailed answer. I'll try now to implement it.
Regarding the 2 cores, we have multiply type of services that uses the same core (PicoCore) as a subtree. The PicoCore has its dependencies, and the specific service has its own dependencies. I would be happy for tips on how to deign it differently from the composer perspective. If I'll rename the folders, All I would need is this line: "PicoCore\\": "", ?

Comment: finish renaming an reinstalling with composer and it now works. also modified the composer to include on the namespace prefix and it works like a charm

Comment: Add the PicoCore as a dependency, don't have it sit in a separate directory. If this adds too much unused code to a project, think about separating it into single packages that depend on each other (but not all of them).

Comment: How can i create a private package out of my PicoCore so it could be added as a dependency ?